# packaging python program in a single executable

Tags: python

Hi I need to package a python program in to a single executable. I need to have a executable that does not need a python installation and third party packages.

So need to have

```
python 2.7.5
WMI==1.4.9
pyjs==0.1.0
pywin32==219
requests==2.4.3
urllib3==1.9.1
```

Is this even possible? I need to able to make a executable to to be run on a freshly installed windows XP+ machine.

I tried pyinstaller  but after that i could not execute the file. Which tool could provide everything needed?

Comment: Have you searched for anything at all? This question has been asked many, many times before.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian It would be helpful if you could locate one such question so that we can close this is a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Py2exe: http://www.py2exe.org/ . It's made for that exact purpose.